# Is it possible to create a UDP and TCP (both) Load Balancer in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcp-load-balancer, google-cloud-compute-engine

I am currently running a game server in a GCE instance. The protocols used are TCP and UDP, and I would need a LB that takes both protocols into account.
At the beggining I created a TCP LB, but obviously I had issues with UDP connections.

I have been checking the official documentation but no good news so far.

I would appreciate if any of you have had a similar case, or any recommendation in order to deal with it in case you think this would not be a correct solution for my use case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud supports External TCP/UDP Load Balancing referred to as [Network Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network). It is a `regional` pass-through load balancer that distributes external traffic among Virtual Machine instances only in the `same region`.

Also, please refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#lb-summary) to know more about GCP's various Load Balancer offerings and their features to see  how they fit with your use case.